# Report asking for database login on setting DataTable as DataSource

Tags: c#, authentication, datatable, crystal-reports, dsn

Report designer creates crystal report in designer with direct connection to database with ODBC (DSN) connection. Same reports are executed via a Winform(C#) application via DSN and provides Database Server, database, user ID and password.

I need to make such changes to the Crystal Report object. ReportDocument should not directly connect to Database via DSN. Instead, we will bring data via service by calling respective stored procedure and parameters as `System.Data.DataTable`. This `DataTable` object should be used to populate/generate reports.

I do get the stored procedure and parameter information from `ReportDocument.DataBase.Tables[I].Location` and `ReportDocument.DataDefinition` object respectively. After setting DataSource with `ReportDocument.DataBase.Tables[I].SetDataSource(DataTable)`, it still ask for database/server and user credential to connect to server.

Can we achieve scenario and populate report with in-memory table instead of direct connection to database over ODBC?

Answer (score 0):

Two things you need to focus on:

1. You are connecting to **same server and database name** which were used to design the report.
2. You are connecting to a **different database or server**.

**Scenario 1: Same server and database name**

In this case you need to provide the credentials using `SetDatabaseLogon` method as follows

```
'crDoc1 is your ReportDocument
'dtDataTable is your DataTable

'set database logon info
crDoc1.SetDatabaseLogon("db_user_name", "db_password", "db_server_name_or_ip", "database_name");

'set DataTable as DataSource
crDoc1.SetDataSource(dtDataTable)
```

**Scenario 2: Different server OR database name**

In this case you need to provide the credentials using `ApplyLogOnInfo` method

```
ConnectionInfo crConInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
TableLogOnInfo crTblLogonInfo = new TableLogOnInfo();

crConInfo.ServerName = "db_server_name_or_ip";
crConInfo.DatabaseName = "database_name";
crConInfo.UserID = "db_user_name";
crConInfo.Password = "db_password";  

'crDoc1 is your ReportDocument
'dtDataTable is your DataTable

'Set DataSource to your DataTable
crDoc1.SetDataSource(dtDataTable)

'after setting the DataSource apply Logon credentials to each table in ReportDocument
Tables CrTables = crDoc1.Database.Tables;
foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables) {
    crTblLogonInfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
    crTblLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = crConInfo;
    CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crTblLogonInfo);
}
crDoc1.Refresh();
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crDoc1;
```

*Notes:* If you have any **sub reports**, you need to apply `SetDatabaseLogon` and/or `ApplyLogOnInfo` to all the sub reports and their tables respectively.

**UPDATE:**
Applying ApplyLogOnInfo to subreports

```
foreach (ReportDocument srSubReport in crDoc1.Subreports) {
    foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in srSubReport.Database.Tables) {
        crTblLogonInfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
        crTblLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = crConInfo;
        CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crTblLogonInfo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would I need to provide database connection information, when I data is already available in DataTable?

Comment: Its security feature of CR to protect data from unauthorized access. DB credentials such as passwords are not saved into reports. When you design crystal report table structure, fields, their type & size, relationships etc. are embedded into report using current database connection and logininfo. When you specify your own disconnected data (DataTables), new schema info must match with existing one. You can have an idea by simply looking into SQL Query of the Crystal Report? So, for data, database verification & security you will have to specify it every time you load a CR.

Comment: Also disconnected data such as DataTable store table structure and data only. There are no Database, Connection details embedded into them.