# Crystal report asks database password and set date format in formula

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, formula, date-format

I have two problems:

1. When I want printout the Crystal Report, get data from SQL using formula, it always requires database password, can I save my password or open connection string using VB?
2. When I get the data from database the date format is like 1986-01-01 01:00AM. Can I make it like 1986-01-01 only?

Code:

```
'CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = New CrystalReport3
'CrystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = "{PersonalData.IDNo}='" + Information.TextBox18.Text + "'"
```

Comment: For database logon query you may check http://stackoverflow.com/a/33246823/5104101

Comment: Date format can be set in the properties of the display field of date in the report design

Comment: Date format is ok now, but i have a question about database login if i make connection using vb how i can set location parameters inside the report because im using to print personal information into id card