# ASP.Net Crystal Reports dataset database login prompt

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I'm modifying an ASP.Net Application to use a new version of crystal reports (13) in Visual Studio 2012. The reports work when I run it locally and they work on an internal test server but they dont' work on our external facing production server where this application has to live.

I get a database login prompt... but I shouldn't because I'm using the "push" method by assigning a datasource to the report. I've combed over every field and I can't imagine what would be mismatched between the dataset and the database and the crystal report. We have also made sure the new version of crystal reports is on the failing server.

Here's the code that loads up the report:

```
 Dim dsWaitsrc As New dsWaitlistDetail

    Using dbConn As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CS_eRegdbConnectionString").ConnectionString)
        Dim cmd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT CL_Index.CL_ID, CL_EMail, CL_Contact, CL_Surname, CL_FirstName, CL_Gender, CL_BirthDate, CL_Income, CL_Reason, CL_Language, CL_Interpretor, CL_WorkingAt, CL_SchoolAt, CL_Marital, CL_Surname2, CL_FirstName2, CL_Gender2, CL_BirthDate2, CL_Income2, CL_Reason2, CL_WorkingAt2, CL_SchoolAt2, CL_Date_Submitted, CL_Index.Updated, CL_Prokids, CL_Resource, CL_ChildCare, CL_Phone, CL_Type, CL_Extension, CL_Phone2, CL_Type2, CL_Extension2, CL_Phone3, CL_Type3, CL_Extension3, (CASE WHEN (CL_Index.CL_Income = 'Ontario Works ( Social Assistance )') THEN '0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CL_Index.CL_Date_Submitted) + STR(CL_Index.CL_ID) ELSE '1' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CL_Index.CL_Date_Submitted) + STR(CL_Index.CL_ID) END) AS rpt_sort, Comments, CL_Camp, PreferredTime, Camp_Type, CL_Behavior, Preference, OtherSource, CH_Surname, CH_FirstName, CH_Gender, CH_BirthDate, CH_Service, ADD_Address, ADD_Unit, ADD_Postal, CL_City FROM CL_Index LEFT OUTER JOIN CL_Addresses ON CL_Index.CL_ID = CL_Addresses.Index_CL_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN CL_City ON CL_Addresses.City_CL_ID = CL_City.CL_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN CL_Children ON CL_Index.CL_ID = CL_Children.Index_CL_ID WHERE CL_Index.CL_ID = " & Request("CL_ID"), dbConn)
        cmd.Connection.Open()

        Using rs As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            While rs.Read
                dsWaitsrc.Tables("CL_Index").Rows.Add(DBString(rs!CL_Contact), DBString(rs!CL_Surname), DBString(rs!CL_FirstName), DBString(rs!CL_Gender), DBDate(rs!CL_BirthDate), DBString(rs!CL_Income), DBString(rs!CL_Reason), DBString(rs!CL_Language), CBool(rs!CL_Interpretor), DBString(rs!CL_WorkingAt), DBString(rs!CL_SchoolAt), DBString(rs!CL_Marital), DBString(rs!CL_Surname2), DBString(rs!CL_FirstName2), DBString(rs!CL_Gender2), DBDate(rs!CL_Birthdate2), DBString(rs!CL_Income2), DBString(rs!CL_Reason2), DBString(rs!CL_WorkingAt2), DBString(rs!CL_SchoolAt2), DBDate(rs!CL_Date_Submitted), CBool(rs!Updated), CBool(rs!CL_ProKids), CBool(rs!CL_Resource), CBool(rs!CL_ChildCare), DBString(rs!CL_Phone), DBString(rs!CL_Type), DBString(rs!CL_Extension), DBString(rs!CL_Phone2), DBString(rs!CL_Type2), DBString(rs!CL_Extension2), DBString(rs!CL_Phone3), DBString(rs!CL_Type3), DBString(rs!CL_Extension3), DBString(rs!CH_Surname), DBString(rs!CH_FirstName), DBString(rs!CH_Gender), DBDate(rs!CH_BirthDate), DBString(rs!ADD_Address), DBString(rs!ADD_Unit), DBString(rs!ADD_Postal), DBString(rs!CL_City), CBool(rs!CH_Service), DBString(rs!rpt_sort), DBInt(rs!CL_ID), DBString(rs!CL_EMail), DBString(rs!Comments), CBool(rs!CL_Camp), DBString(rs!PreferredTime), DBString(rs!Camp_Type), CBool(rs!CL_Behavior), DBString(rs!Preference), DBString(rs!OtherSource))
            End While
        End Using
    End Using

    RPT.setdatasource(dsWaitsrc)
    Me.WaitlistReport.ReportSource = RPT
    Me.WaitlistReport.Visible = True
```

I appreciate any help you can provide to get rid of this database prompt.

Comment: Any change in the db schema will prompt you for login-details. Try implementing this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/33246823/5104101

Comment: That solution is for adding the connection to the report. I don't want to add a connection to the report - instead I'm looking to load it with a dataset, which I've successfully done locally and on the test server given my code but the prod server prompts for login...

Answer (score 0):

You are missing Me.WaitlistReport.DataBind(); after setting ReportSource